# Push to tableViewController Crash in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a button Action in UIViewController, to push to another TableViewController

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(sender : UIButton) {

        let tableVC = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableVCStoryBordId") as MyTableViewController
        self.navigationController .pushViewController(tableVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Crash result is,

```
swift: 11: 11: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)
```

Comment: Isn't Swift an ios8 thing?

Comment: Is there a typo in "tableVCStoryBordId"?

Comment: @Dash: ' tableVCStoryBordId ' it is my storyboard identifier

Comment: You should post the code you have in init(coder:) in the table view controller.

Comment: @jdero, however, it was not a question of the OP, but no... it is not only for iOS8.

Comment: Your init function is wrong. You need to have coder as a parameter because that's the function the storyboard calls to load a viewcontroller. Please try the function in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is happening because the OS cannot find the proper initializer for your MyTableViewController class. Do you have an init(coder) function in that class? It should look something like this:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // any custom init code you want
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you initialize your own variables before calling super.  In Swift you initialize your own before calling super.

Comment: @Eagerod not according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Inheritance.html)

Comment: @MillieSmith, continue on to the next section to see an example where "your own variables" exist. The initialization section's subsection on "Designated and Convenience Initializers in Action" will provide you with a relevant example.

Comment: There is nothing in there that says you must call super only after you init your own variables. It's done sometimes in the examples, but I don't see anything that says "always do it this way". Nor should it. It doesn't make any sense. @Eagerod

Comment: Go ahead and try out the `RecipeIngredient : Food` example that the documentation provides. Calling super.init before initializing your own variables will result in a compiler error to the tune of (in this example, at least) `Property self.quantity not initialized at super.init call`. If you want the actual line that tells you what I'm telling you, go ahead and Control-F "Safety check 1" on the Initialization page.